# How to convert russian text from NSData bytes?

Tags: html, character-encoding, nsstring, char, nsdata

I have a problem. How to convert russian text from NSData?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://pda.somesite"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setAllowCompressedResponse:YES];
[request startSynchronous];
NSLog(@"response %@",[request responseString]);
```

**response (null)**

```
NSLog(@"Length %i", [[request responseData] length]);
```

**Length 11733**

```
char * dataChar = [[request responseData] bytes];
NSLog(@"%s",dataChar);
```

//here i have latin text, but russian simbols are like this **–ñ–∏–≤–æ–µ –æ–±—â–µ–Ω–∏–µ —Å —Ä–µ–∞–ª—å–Ω—ã–º–∏ –ª—é–¥—å–º–∏ —Å–æ –≤—Å–µ–≥–æ –º–∏—Ä–∞!**

```
NSData * newData = [NSData dataWithBytes:dataChar length:127];
```

take first 127 char. If here take more than 127 result is Null!! Why? I have no special symbol after 127. If i take symbols from 127 to 255 this text OK too.

```
NSString * data = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:[newData bytes]];
```

russian simbols looks good but i have string 127 characters long

```
 NSString * str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:dataChar];//str -> (null)
 NSString * str127 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[newData bytes]];//OK but 127 characters
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
char * dataChar = [[request responseData] bytes];
NSLog(@"%s",dataChar);
```

with this

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithCString:[[request responseData] bytes] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
[alert show];
```

then you see, all working fine